# jquery change() does not seem to be working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to accomplish simple calculation on few variables. I need to take the value from the

```
<td class="productprice">
```

and multiply it by the value from the

```
<input type="text" class="quantityBox" value="1"/>
```

And, I am using this piece of code to see if the value change to recalculate.

```
$(".quantityBox").change(function(){
alert("Asdasd");
});
```

And nothing happens. I am expecting the alert box to appear for now, so I'll just be sure that the change works.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: That *should* work, is the jQuery contained within the `$(document).ready(function(){ /* ... */ });`?

Comment: The `change` event for textboxes fires when the input loses focus. Have you tried clicking somewhere else on the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind the change function in document ready event.

Something like:

```
$(function(){
    $(".quantityBox").change(function(){ 
        alert("Asdasd"); 
    }); 
});
```

Note: I assume you are tabbing/moving out of the textbox to see if the change function is firing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you've attached the handler once the DOM is ready, that should work.

Note that the `change` event won't fire until focus has *left* the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8RsXF/ .

If you want to do the calculation after every keypress use `keyup`:

```
$(".quantityBox").keyup(function(){
    alert("Asdasd");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8RsXF/1/

Comment: Does jQuery not support the input event (superior to keyup)?

Comment: @Niel: What `input` event? Where *do* you have an `input` event, and why is it superior to `keyup`? The only downside to using `keyup` is that it doesn't fire when you paste stuff in, which you can easily include via `$('selector').bind('keyup, paste', function(){ ... });)`.

Comment: Why handle a number of events that may or may not have resulted in a change to the field's value when you can bind a single event whose purpose is to indicate that the user has changed the value?

Comment: @Neil: Again, where *do* you have an `input` event?

Comment: Sorry, I'm so used to using it I forgot it wasn't standard until HTML5.